# Listview Items To Html

Tags: html, vb.net

So today im trying to take items and subitems from a listview and put it in my html template. i can see how this is hard to understand so im going to be showing u what i mean.

[image: This is How the Form will look like]

[image: This is the HTML file layout looks like]

This is the Source code for the HTML File

```css
body {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: verdana, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    color: #666666;
    background-color: #333333;
    margin: 0px;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
tr.h th {
    background-color: #333333;
    border: none;
}
th {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #00E5EE;
    border: 1px solid #00E5EE;
    padding: 3px;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
pre {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: verdana, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-weight: normal;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="center" style="margin:auto;width:80%;">
      <table>
        <tr class="h">
          <th>
            <h2>Stats... </h2>
          </th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>age</th>
          <th>gander</th>
        </tr>
        <pre><tr><td>Quan</td><td>12</td><td>male</td></tr></pre>
        <pre><tr><td>sam</td><td>14</td><td>male</td></tr></pre>
      </table>
      <p><small>lit stuff right here </small></p>
    </div>
  </body>
```

So now to tell you what i want happening, i want when i click the button that says "Turn to html" that i show in the form photo, to convert the items and subitems into the html layout that i also show in the second photo.

i hope this is enough information.

Comment: Your approach is totally obscure to what you want to achieve. You have to use `JavaScript ` or `jQuery` and not `css` only. I think you should go look up tutorials on how to use them

Comment: Looking at the first photo in the post I think this is a Windows Forms application. Am I right? Post your code so far, what have you tried?

Comment: @Esko i tried to put a for each so it does it to all of the items in the listview but im bad at that. so i dont really have any thing in the form :(